# Cannot calculate max month value and download images of Modis in partal mouths of 2001 and 2002

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis

I cannot calculate max month value and download images of Modis in partal mouths of 2001 and 2002. There will be something wrong in partial months in 2002 with no vale of NDVI and images. I thought there was something wrong in the fliter. Why and how to improve this code?

[image]

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('users/tejac9759/pinghuamianllsq');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2002-01-01'))
                  .select('NDVI')
                  .map(function(image){
                    return image.multiply(0.0001).set('system:time_start',image.get('system:time_start'))
                                .clip(table)
                  });
var ndviVis = {
  min: -1,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'],
};
Map.centerObject(table, 8);
Map.addLayer(dataset, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
var years = ee.List.sequence(2001, 2001);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var monthly_max =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
    return dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y,y, 'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).max().set('year', y).set('month', m).set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1));
    });
  }).flatten()
);
Map.addLayer(monthly_max.mean().clip(table), ndviVis, 'yearly_mean');
print('Annual max_mounths sequence',ui.Chart.image.series(monthly_max, table, ee.Reducer.mean(), 250));
monthly_max
  .aggregate_array('month')
  .evaluate(function (months) {
    months.forEach(function (month) {
      var image = monthly_max
        .filterMetadata('month', 'equals', month)
        .first()
      var description = 'NDVI_max-'+ '2001_' + month
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: image,
        description: description,
        folder:"monthly_max",
        scale: 250,
        crs: "EPSG:4326",
        maxPixels: 3784216672400,
        region: table,
      });      
    })
})
var NDVImean = ee.Number(monthly_max.mean().reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: table,
scale: 250,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print('NDVImean',NDVImean);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: monthly_max.mean(),
  description: '2001_yearly_mean',
  folder: 'AVHRR_NDVI',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  fileFormat:'GeoTIFF',
  region: table,
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
})
```